# Sprintboot transaction - How to make sure all threads read latest data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I am creating a sprintboot Java application that has following entity

```
Employee - Entity with following fields
id
status // valid values FREE,BUSY
age
```

I have added an API `POST /doTask` which should change the status of the Employee as `BUSY` from `FREE`. The catch here is that Employee takes some time to complete the task and till that time they should not accept any new task. Basically Employee can only do one task at a time.
How do I make sure that when multiple threads all calling `POST /doTask` API, only one manages to assign task and rest all other Requests are given message that Employee is busy ?

I know I can use `@Transactional` annotation, but not sure it works as I am expecting it to. ie. Only one request should be able to update status as `BUSY` and rest all should be able to read this status immediately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out locking. In particular, optimistic locking. When used with application logic that checks the version value, optimistic locking can ensure that no one changes the data out from under the application after it has been read in - so the application will get an OptmisticLockException when it occurs.

Ie:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Version
  @Column(name="VERSION")
  int version;
  ...
}
```

Your Post api then needs to check that the version value hasn't changed since you last read it - JPA should do this for you if you merge in a detached instance back into the context, but you might have to be careful if you read in the entity and perform the merge yourself.

See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Locking for a brief explanation, and there are many tutorials to explain it better.